# How do I list the content of a PPA that I have added to ubuntu?

Tags: ppa

I just added a ppa like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases
```

Now, how do I get to see which packages this PPA contains?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm sure there is many ways to do this - since you have added the PPA, the package details exist in `/var/lib/apt/lists`

Thus for your example `ppa:stebbins/handbrake-releases`

substitute `/` for an `_` and remove the prefix `ppa:` i.e. `stebbins_handbrake-releases`

Then just use this *repositoryname* in the following command line entry:

```
cat /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_[repositoryname]_*_Packages | grep "Package:" | sort | uniq
```

i.e.

```
cat /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_stebbins_handbrake-releases_*_Packages | grep "Package:" | sort | uniq
```

On newer versions of Debian the Packages file is LZ4 compressed, so you'll need to `apt-get install liblz4-tool` and then insert an `lz4cat` step into your pipeline to decompress it:

```
lz4cat /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_stebbins_handbrake-releases_*_Packages | grep "Package:" | sort | uniq
```

This will list the contents:

```
Package: handbrake-cli
Package: handbrake-gtk
```

Comment: You can shorten this slightly by rearranging to `grep "Package:" /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_..._Packages | sort -u`

Comment: This works perfect (if one remembers to do 'sudo apt-get update' after adding the PPA...)

Comment: You can also go to Launchpad to see the information.  Assume first that the `ppa:` example you gave is in the form: `ppa:team/archivename`.  The corresponding LaunchPad link would be `https://launchpad.net/~team/+archive/archivename`.

Comment: In addition to what Oli said,   it'd be better to use the `-h` flag in  `grep -h 'Package:'  /var/lib/apt/lists/ppa.launchpad.net_*_Packages` to print just the packages without printing the filename itself.

Comment: On newer versions of Debian the Packages file is LZ4 compressed, so you'll need to `apt-get install liblz4-tool` and then insert an `lz4cat -d` step into your pipeline to decompress it.

Answer (score 9):

To see the content of a ppa you can use Y PPA Manager. Install it by running the following in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install y-ppa-manager
```

When the application is started, click on Manage PPA's:

[image]

Select the PPA you want to see the content of:

[image]

And finally click on "list packages" to see all packages provided by the given PPA.

Hopefully this will help.